# React-Native fetch() and requests end up in a Network error

Tags: react-native, request

I followed a lot of tutorials regarding calling an API with axios this is what I am trying (emulated device Android 11):

```
const TryScreen= ({ navigation }) => {
  function getthe(){
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/hacktivist123/repos')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button buttonStyle={styles.loginButton} onPress={() => getthe()} title="Get" />
    </View>
  );
};
```

But my console just tell me all the time:

```
W/ReactNativeJS: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5):
    TypeError: Network request failed
    http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:26035:33
    _callTimer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30531:17
    callTimers@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30739:19
    __callFunction@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2765:36
    http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2497:31
    __guard@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2719:15
    callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2496:21
    callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

if I am using localhost, it's works fine, but why can I not call an remote api? Tried Axios as well with the same result. Postman on the same machine is doing also get the expectet result.
I am using "react-native": "0.63.3"

Answer (score 0):

Add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to ./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest:

```
<application
       ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 ...>
```

If you want to enable HTTP requests add this to your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: thank you. I did that already, with the same result. Also as you can see I am using a https connection, but thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `.catch(error => { /* HANDLE ERRROR */ })`

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/hacktivist123/repos')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log(error)); //Add this
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: unfortuanetly not. It only give me the err: [TypeError: Network request failed]

Answer (score 0):

You can run `adb logcat` in terminal to get emulator's log and see if you can get more details.

Comment: More? My terminal is exploding ;-) I can't read it and it's too much to post.

Comment: after u get the network error, Ctrl+C to stop logcat and look for the error in the log. I believe the log has better error description and u can google it